# Abrir fichero y almacenar datos procedentes de arrays con codificación ASCII

Tags: python, python-2.7, archivo, matplotlib

Estoy intentando resolver el siguiente ejercicio:

> Si tienen N iteraciones en su versión del código ***bounce.py***, modifíquenlo para que en la iteración N - 20 escriba un archivo en formato ASCII con las siguientes columnas: pos(x), vel(x), pos(y), vel(y). El archivo debe tener n lineas (donde n =numero de pelotas), y 4 columnas.

El código del que parto es el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])

n = 10
pos = (20 * np.random.sample(n*2) - 10).reshape(n, 2)
vel = (0.3 * np.random.normal(size=n*2)).reshape(n, 2)
sizes = 100 * np.random.sample(n) + 100

colors = np.random.sample([n, 4])

circles = plt.scatter(pos[:,0], pos[:,1], marker='o', s=sizes, c=colors)

for i in range(100):
    pos = pos + vel
    bounce = abs(pos) > 10      
    vel[bounce] = -vel[bounce]  
    circles.set_offsets(pos)    
    plt.draw()
    plt.show()
```

He intentado resolverlo usando un condicional en el ciclo, pero me encuentro con un error:

---

> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> /home/wamba/Documentos/UdeC/11° Semestre/Software/bounce2.py in <module>()
>          26 for i in range(100):
>          27     if i==100-20:
> ---> 28         with open('posandvel.txt', 'w+', 'utf-8') as f:
>      29             list= [pos[:,0],vel[:,0],pos[:,1],vel[:,1]]
>      30             f.write('posicion x\t velocidad x\t posicion y\t velocidad y\n')
>
> TypeError: an integer is required
> ```

Este es el código que estoy intentando:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mplt
import codecs

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])

n = 10
pos = (20 * np.random.sample(n*2) - 10).reshape(n, 2)
vel = (0.3 * np.random.normal(size=n*2)).reshape(n, 2)
sizes = 100 * np.random.sample(n) + 100

colors = np.random.sample([n, 4])


stars = plt.scatter(pos[:,0], pos[:,1], marker='*', s=sizes, c=colors)


angle=0
for i in range(100):
    if i==100-20:
       with open('posandvel.txt', 'w+', 'utf-8') as f:
         list= [pos[:,0],vel[:,0],pos[:,1],vel[:,1]]
         f.write('posicion x\t velocidad x\t posicion y\t velocidad y\n')

pos = pos + vel
bounce = abs(pos) > 10     
angle=angle+10
pos[bounce] = -pos[bounce]

stars.set_offsets(pos)   
plt.pause(0.05)
```

Comment: Camila he creado una respuesta explicando la causa del error y como corregirlo. No obstante, hay una incongruencia en tu pregunta ya que en el código intentas usar UTF-8 como encoding pero en el título mencionas ASCII. Deberías aclarar esto, aunque no es la causa directa del error que muestras.

Answer (score 2):

El erro es que tanto en Python 2 como en Python 3 el tercer argumento de [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) es `buffering`, que es un entero y se encarga de establecer el comportamiento del buffer.

Si usaras Python 3, el argumento que intentas usar es `encoding`, para ello pásalo por palabra clave, no por posición:

```
with open('posandvel.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Si usas Python 2, el argumento `encoding` no existe. Puedes usar el módulo `io` de la biblioteca estándar para obtener el comportamiento de `open` en Python 3:

```
with io.open('posandvel.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

No obstante, si el fichero a de se ASCII simplemente no uses ningún encoding, simplemente ábrelo en modo de escritura.

Unas cuantas observaciones:

- No uses `list` como un nombre para tus variables. `list` es una función built-in en Python y con esto la sobrescribes, es poco legible y puedes acabar teniendo errores si se intenta usar posteriormente.
- Deberías usar una variable para el número de iteraciones en vez de hardcodear en el propio `for`. Por otro lado, si debes guardar los datos de la iteración I-20 debes hacer la comparación con `if i == ITERACIONES - 21` ya que `i` en `range(ITERACIONES)` empieza por 0.
- Tienes un error en la identación, las cinco últimas líneas deben estar dnetro del `for`, en caso contrario no obtendrás la animación.

Para escribir las líneas tienes varias opciones, entre ellas usar `str.format` junto a `zip`, algo parecido a lo que pretendías hacer al crear tu variable `list`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



N = 10
ITERATIONS = 100

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])

pos = (20 * np.random.sample(N * 2) - 10).reshape(N, 2)
vel = (0.3 * np.random.normal(size=N * 2)).reshape(N, 2)
sizes = 100 * np.random.sample(N) + 100
colors = np.random.sample([N, 4])


circles = plt.scatter(pos[:,0], pos[:,1], marker='o', s=sizes, c=colors)

for i in range(ITERATIONS):
    if i == ITERATIONS - 21: # i empieza en 0
        with open('posandvel.txt', 'w+') as f:
            f.writelines("{},{},{},{}\n".format(x, vx, y , vy)
                         for x, vx, y, vy in zip(pos[:,0], vel[:,0], pos[:,1], vel[:,1]))

    pos = pos + vel
    bounce = abs(pos) > 10      
    vel[bounce] = -vel[bounce]  
    circles.set_offsets(pos)    
    plt.pause(0.05)
```

Otra opción es usar `range`:

```
f.writelines("{},{},{},{}\n".format(pos[j, 0], vel[j, 0], pos[j, 1] , vel[j ,1])
             for j in range(N))
```

Dado que en esencia lo que creas es un archivo csv puedes usar el módulo `csv` para esto:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




N = 10
ITERATIONS = 100

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])

pos = (20 * np.random.sample(N * 2) - 10).reshape(N, 2)
vel = (0.3 * np.random.normal(size=N * 2)).reshape(N, 2)
sizes = 100 * np.random.sample(N) + 100
colors = np.random.sample([N, 4])


circles = plt.scatter(pos[:,0], pos[:,1], marker='o', s=sizes, c=colors)

for i in range(ITERATIONS):
    if i == ITERATIONS - 21: # i empieza en 0
        with open('posandvel.txt', 'wb') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows((pos[j, 0], vel[j, 0], pos[j, 1] , vel[j, 1])
                              for j in range(N))

    pos = pos + vel
    bounce = abs(pos) > 10      
    vel[bounce] = -vel[bounce]  
    circles.set_offsets(pos)    
    plt.pause(0.05)
```

O usar NumPy directamente con `numpy.savetxt`:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




N = 10
ITERATIONS = 100

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])

pos = (20 * np.random.sample(N * 2) - 10).reshape(N, 2)
vel = (0.3 * np.random.normal(size=N * 2)).reshape(N, 2)
sizes = 100 * np.random.sample(N) + 100
colors = np.random.sample([N, 4])


circles = plt.scatter(pos[:,0], pos[:,1], marker='o', s=sizes, c=colors)

for i in range(ITERATIONS):
    if i == ITERATIONS - 21: # i empieza en 0
        np.savetxt('posandvel.txt',
                   np.column_stack((pos[:,0], vel[:,0], pos[:, 1], vel[:,1])),
                   delimiter=",",
                   fmt='%1.5f') # 5 decimales

    pos = pos + vel
    bounce = abs(pos) > 10      
    vel[bounce] = -vel[bounce]  
    circles.set_offsets(pos)    
    plt.pause(0.05)
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda pero al hacer todos esos arreglos incluso el nombre list lo cambie por axis para que no hubiera problemas pero la terminal me arroja un error de: name 'io' is not defined

Comment: @Camila perdona  se me pasó indicarlo de forma explícita, debes importar el módulo `io` al inicio de tu script: `import io`. Recuerda que si usas Python 3 no tienes que usar `io`, con el buit-in `open` puedes especificar el encoding sin problemas. Un saludo.

Comment: me puedes enviar tu correo por favor ya que ahi podria escribir el codigo completo, muchas gracias.

Comment: en el siguiente link se encuentra la pregunta mejor formulada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150276/crear-un-archivo-ascii-en-python-2-7-13

Comment: Camila no debes duplicar preguntas, en su lugar usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150241/c%c3%b3mo-leer-un-archivo-de-datos-con-ascii/150244?noredirect=1#comment281459_150244) que hay debajo de tu pregunta original y añade en ella la información. He editado la respuesta, mira al final de ella a ver si es lo que buscas.